# Why does the radius of curvature is constant in $n$-$t$ coordinate kinematics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, kinematics, coordinate-systems, rotational-kinematics

Deriving the relations kinematics on an **$n$-$t$ coordinate** system is said that if we have a particle $A$,after differential of time $dt$ the particle moves to $A'$. Assuming a **curvilinear motion**, the arc length between $A-A'$ describes by the particle's path can be expressed as a differential of length $ds$ equivalent to the radius $ \rho $ with respect to the center of curvature at $t$ times the differential angle $ d\beta$. Hence $ ds = \rho d\beta $. Deriving with respect to time, it's said the we should get an speed $dv = \rho \frac{d\beta}{dt} = \rho \dot\beta$ . However, it exists the possibility of having a no constant $\rho(t) $ ? In that case the $ dv$ shouldn't take into account that variation? In the book they said that:

> It is unnecessary to consider the differential change in $\rho$ between A and A′ because a higher-order term would be introduced which disappears in the limit

I don't quite get that idea. In a curvilinear motion the center of curvature C can variate, and **possibly** changing $\rho $. Is there something I'm missing? Why does $ \rho $ is treated as a constant?

[image: Taken from 8th Dynamics (Meriam and Kraige)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the thing: the displacement is so small that "it has no space to vary". We're drawing it big, but we are considering so small dispalcements that curves can be approximated by circle arcs.

The real curve might start diverging from that point aftewrwards, but in such small interval, teh tangent point can be extended to a tiny environment around it. So we can say that any curvature is **locally** like a circle arc. That will cease to be true after some distance, but for so small dispalcements, it's true. The curves are actually completely overlapped.